# How To Make An iOS PhotoScroller Without Tiles?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I've downloaded the sample code from the apple developer's library, and I've been trying to change the sample code to display images without tiles.

I've been having  a hard time, I've tried everything, but the screen always just comes out blank, or it comes out black with tile lines.

and I have changed the data from the imageData.plist to my pictures. can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm attempting to do the same thing.  I just noticed this comment in [PhotoViewController configurePage:forIndex:]:

```
// To use full images instead of tiled images, replace the "displayTiledImageNamed:" call
// above by the following line:
// [page displayImage:[self imageAtIndex:index]];
```

Comment: When Scrolling I immediately receive a memory warning.. trying this.

Comment: Yeah, if the images are too large you need to tile, that's the point of tiling, to reduce the memory footprint.  This should work fine for smaller images.

Comment: @Tieme did you use the tile.did it work perfectly? I am also getting memory issue for displaying photo library images.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of that example is using tiles. If you just want to display an image in a UIScrollView this [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904) is more likely to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of `ImageScrollView.m`, change the line from:

```
#define TILE_IMAGES 1
```

to:

```
#define TILE_IMAGES 0
```

This will stop the app from tiling the images.